# functions limits

Tags: calculus, limits

In question No.9 why we can not conclude anything about f at x=1 ? I did not really get it so can someone explain it for me ?
[image: .]

[image: .]

Comment: Take the function $f(x)=5$ for all real $x\ne 1$ and an arbitary value for $x=1$. Whatever its value is for $x=1$, the limit for $x\rightarrow 1$ is $5$ because if we approach $1$ from either side, the value approaches $5$. With the additional condition that $f$ is continous at $x=1$, we could include $f(1)=5$.

Comment: As an aside, for problem 10 just reverse the role of the various numbers in the answers below.  The end takeaway is that $f(c)$ can be different than $\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)$.  Functions where $f(c)=\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)$ for all $c$ are called continuous functions and play a special role in mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the definition we have $$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta, 0<|x-x_0|<\delta\to |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$for some $L$ where nowhere restricts the value of the function at the exact point. For example consider the following function$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{5x-5}{x-1}&x\ne 1\\a&x=1\end{cases}$$for different values of $a$. In fact if any function satisfies $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$$the function is referred to as $\text{continuous at }x=a$

Answer (score 1):

The definition of limit at $x_0$ is independent of the value of the function at $x_0$. Check the definition!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function

$$f(x)~=~\begin{cases}
     5x~\text{, for } x\in \mathbb{R}/\{1\} \\
     42~\text{, for } x=1 \\ \end{cases} $$

while the limit for sure goes for $x=1$ to $5$ the functions is defined in another way at this point. You can construct functions like this with ease and there is the problem.